# Android: addHeader to ListView

Tags: android, listview, header

I'm trying to add a header to my `listView` but I see only black screen when activity launches

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maincoverflow);

        final ListView itemslist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.itemslist);        
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        ViewGroup mTop = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_header, itemslist, false);
        itemslist.addHeaderView(mTop, null, false);

        //some actions with header and list items
        //example: coverflow_item_title is located in header(R.layout.main_header)
        title = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.coverflow_item_title); //checked - is not null

        CoverFlow coverFlow =  (CoverFlow) findViewById(R.id.coverflow);
        ImageAdapter coverImageAdapter =  new ImageAdapter(this);
        coverFlow.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        coverImageAdapter.createImages();

        coverFlow.setAdapter(coverImageAdapter);  
        coverFlow.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CoverAdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){           
           ...
           adapter = new LazyAdapter(MainCoverflowActivity.this, tools, tools_images);
           itemslist.setAdapter(adapter); 
        }

        itemslist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
               ...
        }
}
```

maincoverflow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/itemslist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

main_header.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coverflow_item_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <com.thumbsupstudio.mobitour.CoverFlow
        android:id="@+id/coverflow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shadowbox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/shadow_box" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You may notice that I'm using `Coverflow` widget (from here http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html) - it works fine.

In general, I'm changing `listView` content when `Coverflow` item is changed. It works fine, but I need `Coverflow` to scroll with `listView`, so I decided to attach it to header. After that, there's no `listView` and `Coverflow` on the screen, everything is black.

Comment: Have you checked your adapter after adding the header? When you add a header, the positions of the items increases by 1 due to the header. I hope that is not messing up your list.

Comment: did you tried hierarchyviewer to see where your items are positioned?

Comment: @Shubhayu I'm setting list adapter after adding the header. I think if a position number shift takes place and it matters then some error should occur, so I have just black screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I don't fully understand WHY but:

**NOT CORRECT**

```
init listView
inflate header and add it to the list
set list adapter in Coverflow onItemSelected handler (it launch automatically with item position=0)
```

**CORRECT**

```
init listView
inflate header and add it to the list
set any adapter to listView (!!!)
set listView adapter in Coverflow onItemSelected handler (it launch automatically with item position=0)
```

after activity launches `listView` has adapter content which was set in Coverflow `onItemSelected` handler. What for is first adapter assignment - I don't understand.

Comment: I had completely overlooked this yesterday! Until and unless you set the adapter, the list will not be generated. You are creating the coverflow and setting it as the header, but setting the adapter of the list containing the coverflow header happens only in onItemSelected(). Which basically means that the list is never created in the first place!

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/coverflow_item_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <com.thumbsupstudio.mobitour.CoverFlow
        android:id="@+id/coverflow"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shadowbox"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/shadow_box" />

</RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/itemslist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i think the issue here is to have the header scroll with the list view.

Comment: yes, I need header scrolling too. I think that code won't allow it